# Rest service post bean validation

Tags: web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am stuck with a problem of post body attributes validation. I need to throw an exception or show an error, when an invalid attribute is passed down to JSON request body. I have no idea how to do that? Please help.

FYI : I am using Jersey API.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you use Jersey's bean validation support examples and docs- [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)?

Bean Validation support in Jersey is provided as an extension module and needs to be mentioned explicitly in your pom.xml file (in case of using Maven): 
`<dependency> 
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId> 
<artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId> 
<version>2.22.1</version> 
</dependency>`

you can define your custom validations and ValidationError messages.

In JSP add validation-errors tags and you are done.

```
<div class="validation-errors">
    <div class="validation-error">
```

Or even you can sent json format error response.

```
[ {
   "message" : "xxxxxx.",
   "messageTemplate" : "{xxx.does.not.exist}",
   "path" : "abc.xyz.<return value>"
} ]
```

Comment: I have tried to use few bean validation annotation eg. @Valid. But this annotation is not present with javax.ws.rs.api-2.0.jar. Therefore, I am unable to use it.

Comment: What stop you from adding it?   Bean Validation support in Jersey is provided as an extension module and needs to be mentioned explicitly in your pom.xml file (in case of using Maven):
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>